# How to correctly rename a SplitContainer WinForms control and its panels?

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I've placed a split container on a form and want to rename it and its panels to something meaningful (as I am going to add more SplitContainers on this form). Butwhen I rename splitContainer1 to mainSplitContainer, its panels are still named splitContainer1.Panel1 and splitContainer1.Panel2 (while i already have no object called splitContainer1) and I can't find a way to fix this. Do you know the way?

Comment: What version of VS are you running?  In VS 2005 at least on my machine, the designer correctly renames all references, including the panel references.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 (not a beta)

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename panels, because these are properties not embedded controls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global search and replace.  This is accessed by [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [H]

Comment: Seems a bit too brutal when working with visual designer. But yes, I know I can and I shall try if there is no more lawful way.

Comment: Just a little warning: I've just tried a global search and replace and it's destroyed my project :-( I guess it must have duplicated a control name or something